# Swap character of string in Python

Tags: python

Is there any simple way to swap character of string in python. In my case I want to swap `.` and `,` from `5.123.673,682`. So my string should become `5,123,673.682`.

I have tried:

```
number = '5.123.673,682'
number = number.replace('.', 'temp')
number = number.replace(',', '.')
number = number.replace('temp', ',')
print(number) # 5,123,673.682
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that what you have done is the simplest way to accomplish this.

Comment: maybe as simple as like variable swap x,y=y,x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `dict.get`:

```
mapper = {".": ",", ",":"."}

"".join([mapper.get(s, s) for s in '5.123.673,682'])
```

Or using `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`:

```
'5.123.673,682'.translate(str.maketrans(".,", ",."))
```

Output:

```
'5,123,673.682'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pythonic and clean approach to do that

```py
def swap(c):
  if c == ',': return '.'
  elif c == '.': return ','
  else: return c

number = '5.123.673,682'
new_number = ''.join(swap(o) for o in number)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to swap single characters, think of it as a mapping instead

```
def mapping(c):
  if c == ',': return '.'
  if c == '.': return ','
  return c

number = '5.123.673,682'
converted = ''.join(map(mapping, number))
print(converted)
```

5,123,673.682