# How to 'swap' words (multiple characters) in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Consider the following examples:

```
string_now = 'apple and avocado'
stringthen = string_now.swap('apple', 'avocado') # stringthen = 'avocado and apple'
```

and:

```
string_now = 'fffffeeeeeddffee'
stringthen = string_now.swap('fffff', 'eeeee') # stringthen = 'eeeeefffffddffee'
```

Approaches discussed in [Swap character of string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964188/swap-character-of-string-in-python) do not work, as the mapping technique used there only takes one character into consideration. Python's built-in `str.maketrans()` also only supports one-character translations, as when I try to do multiple characters, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.maketrans(mapper)
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
```

A chain of `replace()` methods is not only far from ideal (since I have many replacements to do, chaining replaces would be a big chunk of code) but because of its sequential nature, it will not translate things perfectly as:

```
string_now = 'apple and avocado'
stringthen = string_now.replace('apple', 'avocado').replace('avocado', 'apple')
```

gives `'apple and apple'` instead of `'avocado and apple'`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a character that's guaranteed to not be in the string? For example `\n`?

Comment: What should `'applemon'.swap('apple', 'lemon')` produce?

Comment: @KellyBundy this is an interesting case but for my cases there wont be any such case. where they overlap. It can either be `'applemon'.swap('apple', 'mon')` or `'applemon'.swap('app', 'lemon')`. But it sure is a very interesting case to look at.

Comment: There is no character tho which can never occur. Especially new line almost always occurs in multi-sentence lines

Comment: Old message on [python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-April/004005.html) :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given that we want to swap words `x` and `y`, and that we don't care about the situation where they overlap, we can:

- split the string on occurrences of `x`
- within each piece, replace `y` with `x`
- join the pieces with `y`

Essentially, we use split points within the string as a temporary marker to avoid the problem with sequential replacements.

Thus:

```
def swap_words(s, x, y):
    return y.join(part.replace(y, x) for part in s.split(x))
```

Test it:

```
>>> swap_words('apples and avocados and avocados and apples', 'apples', 'avocados')
'avocados and apples and apples and avocados'
>>>
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to go about it as it doesn't assume any characters not appearing and avoid sequential replacement issues very elegantly

Comment: very Pythonic 

Answer (score 9):

Two regex solutions and one for other people who do have a character that can't appear (there are over a million different possible characters, after all) and who don't dislike `replace` chains :-)

```
def swap_words_regex1(s, x, y):
    return re.sub(re.escape(x) + '|' + re.escape(y),
                  lambda m: (x if m[0] == y else y),
                  s)

def swap_words_regex2(s, x, y):
    return re.sub(f'({re.escape(x)})|{re.escape(y)}',
                  lambda m: x if m[1] is None else y,
                  s)

def swap_words_replaces(s, x, y):
    return s.replace(x, chr(0)).replace(y, x).replace(chr(0), y)
```

Some benchmark results:

```
 3.7 ms  1966 kB  swap_words_split
10.7 ms  2121 kB  swap_words_regex1
17.8 ms  2121 kB  swap_words_regex2
 1.3 ms   890 kB  swap_words_replaces
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPbbqMwEH3nK@YNu4toaPqwQsrLfkB/oKqQA0PqXXyR7WyDUr49OwZKEyWt1khgH885HM@MbR9ejV7/tO50ap1REKRCGUAqa1wAhxZFSJbVxyw4UaMSXWdqEB6CSpIGW/BvwlZvxjW@8raTgfkMDhn0vEyAhsOwdxr6/LeRmlnhQk4/6EiK9RTIoTUOIgxSg88niQPnV@IOd3gobqs7zP1@y@iDvhYWSQB@QPqe0vsT7Hk2ki5HJ9S2EaBKYAeQLajn1QtsNtADdh7hNsl/4e/hW39tyo7nHgf@fjy3N6TfG5z9FS8gPTwZjbPF/3Y45t3f9uiXutBe/erYivPLUi2raTcqJEm717WHzVUbZNe1u4Yeslv@kkS4XdRMhbUdehC6AfHX1KIx02IrND3T3Dihd3NQCndQrGhkH9w0zmZqSm6p2arYaSOJrecURDgeJO6MByqXjAbyoahzp1vBpmKUYxS7iz4pD3qvtug2BXXtQlO5D9TV7BM6oyyYQmVcT7@g@B2GarxjTTXBjFOpLxWNPRO0TupATXUM8di4Lh/zoh1AeYDjLHx/P@ajfBzgzy@Co4e8qrRQWFVDOmlNOvx0@gc)):

```
from timeit import repeat
import re
import tracemalloc as tm

def swap_words_split(s, x, y):
    return y.join(part.replace(y, x) for part in s.split(x))

def swap_words_regex1(s, x, y):
    return re.sub(re.escape(x) + '|' + re.escape(y),
                  lambda m: (x if m[0] == y else y),
                  s)

def swap_words_regex2(s, x, y):
    return re.sub(f'({re.escape(x)})|{re.escape(y)}',
                  lambda m: x if m[1] is None else y,
                  s)

def swap_words_replaces(s, x, y):
    return s.replace(x, chr(0)).replace(y, x).replace(chr(0), y)

funcs = swap_words_split, swap_words_regex1, swap_words_regex2, swap_words_replaces

args = 'apples and avocados and bananas and oranges and ' * 10000, 'apples', 'avocados'

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(*args), number=1))
        tm.start()
        func(*args)
        memory = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
        tm.stop()
        print(f'{t * 1e3:4.1f} ms  {memory // 1000:4} kB  {func.__name__}')
    print()
```

Comment: Why would anyone not like replace chain? `swap_words_replaces` is the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: @FanchenBao You'll have to ask the OP, they wrote it's "far from ideal" but I don't know why. I think most elegant is the split+join solution, though.

Comment: Yes it is elegant when I have one or two replacements to do. Since I have originally a large number of replacements to do, split-join approach works better as I can loop through them applying function for each operation however while chaining replaces it would be a big chunk of code

Comment: @Hamza Huh? Why couldn't you do the exact same looping as for the split-join approach?

Answer (score 3):

### This solution uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```py
string_now = "apple and avocado"
stringthen = (  # "avocado and apple"
    string_now.replace("apple", "{apple}")
    .replace("avocado", "{avocado}")
    .format(apple="avocado", avocado="apple")
)

# Edit: as a function
def swap_words(s, x, y):
    return s.replace(x, "{" + x + "}")
            .replace(y, "{" + y + "}")
            .format(**{x: y, y: x})
```

It first adds curly brackets before and after keywords to turn them into placeholders. Then `str.format()` is used to replace the placeholders.

Comment: Kudos to [@nikeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209111/python-best-way-to-swap-words-multiple-characters-in-a-string#comment124220330_70210662) for making me think about this solution.

Comment: Wouldn't work if `{apples}` is already present in the string: then it would be replaced first with `{{apples}}`, and at the format stage reduce back down to `{apples}` based on Python string formatting convention

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a temp string which will never be in the origin string?

for example:

```
>>> a = 'apples and avocados and avocados and apples'
>>> b = a.replace('apples', '#IamYourFather#').replace('avocados', 'apples').replace('#IamYourFather#', 'avocados')
>>> print(b)
avocados and apples and apples and avocados
```

where `#IamYourFather#` is a string which will never be in the origin string.

Comment: Since I am not sure about what strings can NEVER occur, but still this is useful for such cases

Comment: @Hamaza md5(your name or birthday) is enough.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to make this function that does exactly what you want.

```
def swapwords(mystr, firstword, secondword):
    splitstr = mystr.split(" ")

    for i in range(len(splitstr)):
        if splitstr[i] == firstword:
            splitstr[i] = secondword
            i+=1
        if splitstr[i] == secondword:
            splitstr[i] = firstword
            i+=1

    newstr = " ".join(splitstr)

   return newstr
```

Basically, what this does is it takes in your string `"Apples and Avacados"`, and splits it by spaces. Thus, each word gets indexed in an array `splitstr[]`. Using this, we can use a for loop to swap the words. The `i+=1` is in order to ensure the words don't get swapped twice. Lastly, I join the string back using `newstr= " ".join(splitstr)` which joins the words separated by a space.

Running the following code gives us:
`Avacados and Apples`.

Comment: You should use `if..elif` instead of two separate `if`s. Then, you don't need `i += 1`. The `for` loop automatically takes the next element of the iterable in the next iteration. In fact, you could do `i += 100` and it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Also, your code breaks with `swapwords("apples avocados and avocados", "apples", "avocados")`.